# replace pandas column values with counts

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Pandas GroupBy and replace value with normalized counts

Sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(10,3)),columns=["c1","c2","c3"])
df["r1"]=["Apple","Mango","Apple","Mango","Mango","Mango","Apple","Mango","Apple","Apple"]
df["r2"]=["Orange","lemon","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon","lemon","Orange","lemon"]
df["date"] = ["2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01",
              "2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01"]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df
```

DF:

```
    c1      c2      c3     r1        r2       date
0   10       2       0     Apple    Orange  2002-01-01
1   10      10      13     Mango    lemon   2002-01-01
2   0       12       0     Apple    lemon   2002-01-01
3   1       13       8     Mango    Orange  2002-01-01
4   6        5       9     Mango    lemon   2002-01-01
5   3       18      13     Mango    Orange  2002-01-01
6   2        6       7     Apple    lemon   2002-02-01
7   0        4       7     Mango    lemon   2002-02-01
8   1       10      19     Apple    Orange  2002-02-01
9   11      18       2     Apple    lemon   2002-02-01
```

I am trying to groupby the `date` column and replace selected columns with normalized count.

For example:

in the group `2002-01-01` the column `r1`  values `Apple` will be replaced by `0.3` since in this group there are `6` records and `2`records have `Apple` so `2/6` and `Mango` will be replaced by `4/6` which is `0.6`

Pandas Solution:

```
df.groupby("date")[["r1","r2"]].apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Is there a pandas way to do this instead of a iterative `iterrows` solution.

Comment: Can you provide the output you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `value_counts` + `normalize`

```
df['New']=df.groupby(['date']).r1.value_counts(normalize=True).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['date','r1']])).values
df
   c1  c2  c3     r1      r2       date       New
0   1   8   2  Apple  Orange 2002-01-01  0.333333
1   8   1   7  Mango   lemon 2002-01-01  0.666667
2   0  14   8  Apple   lemon 2002-01-01  0.333333
3  11  13  10  Mango  Orange 2002-01-01  0.666667
4  15   4  15  Mango   lemon 2002-01-01  0.666667
5  13   7   7  Mango  Orange 2002-01-01  0.666667
6   7   0  14  Apple   lemon 2002-02-01  0.750000
7  13   5  11  Mango   lemon 2002-02-01  0.250000
8  19  17  11  Apple  Orange 2002-02-01  0.750000
9   8   1   9  Apple   lemon 2002-02-01  0.750000
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. So I cannot do for both the columns ```r1 and r2``` in 1 go is it?

Comment: @vikky for both column you need find the combination percentage ?

Comment: yes, the exact solution applied to both columns simultaneously. Can I do that?

Comment: @vikky you can  df[‘New’]=df[[‘r1’,’r2’]].apply(tuple ,1);df.groupby(['date']).New.value_counts(normalize=True).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['date','New']])).values

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` method to get the size of each group and assign this value to each row of the original dataframe.

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['date', 'r1'])['c1'].transform(len)/df.groupby(['date'])['c1'].transform(len)                                                    
Out[11]: 
0    0.333333
1    0.666667
2    0.333333
3    0.666667
4    0.666667
5    0.666667
6    0.750000
7    0.250000
8    0.750000
9    0.750000
Name: c1, dtype: float64
```

and if you need to get rounded value, just use `round` method.